# Uncaught TypeError: n.Telemetry.PageViewPerformance.checkPageLoad is not a function

Tags: azure-application-insights, datazen-server

All our Microsoft Datazen servers are seeing an infine loop of client side javascript exceptions:

```
Uncaught TypeError: n.Telemetry.PageViewPerformance.checkPageLoad is not a function
```

since this script comes from http://az416426.vo.msecnd.net/scripts/a/ai.0.js the issue may be the App Insights cloud service.

As anyone experienced this?

Answer (score 0):

Interesting - there was a refactoring recently where 'checkPageLoad' was split to 2 other functions (https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS/commit/da50064bfc6537fe7efe78ef1f5b048636f85070#diff-e25ffb54668c8e8794fb7224dbfadafbL112) However I don't see any issues with that - all usages of checkPageLoad were corrected accordingly.
Was it an intermittent issue or is it still reproducing? Do you have any custom code calling into AppInsights script, or it's just a snippet that you injected into your page?